# Installing ElasticSearch plugins

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch

I'm trying to install an ElasticSearch plugin on Ubuntu 12.04, and the documentation is not helping me.  The plugin is distributed as a jar, and I've tried installing it with the plugin command without apparent success:

```
[13:28:38][root@pre-staging:/usr/share/elasticsearch]$ curl -I file:///usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins-no/elasticsearch-knapsack-1.0.3.jar
Content-Length: 322631
Accept-ranges: bytes
Last-Modified: Thu, 13 Dec 2012 18:47:04 GMT
[13:29:56][root@pre-staging:/usr/share/elasticsearch]$ bin/plugin -url file:///usr/share/elasticsearch/plugins-no/elasticsearch-knapsack-1.0.3.jar
[13:30:01][root@pre-staging:/usr/share/elasticsearch]$ ls plugins
[13:30:03][root@pre-staging:/usr/share/elasticsearch]$
```

You can see that the jar file exists, but when I install it nothing happens to the plugins directory.  I've also tried manually adding the jar to the plugins directory.  I have no idea whether that's supposed to work, or whether I'd see something in the elasticsearch log if I did things right, but I don't, and I don't see the behavior the plugin's documentation makes me expect I should.  I've also followed the plugin's installation instructions directly, https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-knapsack, which don't do anything useful either (the installation can't find whatever remote files it expects to install the plugin).

So the question is - How do I install this plugin?  How can I tell if it's been installed correctly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `plugin` command doesn't do anything special, it just tries to download the zip file from different locations and extracts it to a specific subfolder under plugins. Most of the plugins used to be available directly as GitHub downloads, but since GitHub [has disabled its downloads feature](https://github.com/blog/1302-goodbye-uploads), there is a discussion going on about what's the best way to work around this. The plugins coming from the elasticsearch team have been moved to `download.elasticsearch.org` and the plugin command has been lately updated to reflect this change. Have a look at the related [issue](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/2507) and this [blogpost](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/2012/12/17/new-download-service.html) about it.

Anyway, if you have problems using the plugin command you can just download the zip file and extract it to a specific subfolder under plugins. After that you need to restart your elasticsearch node and you'll see in the output a list of plugins that have been found and succesfully loaded during startup. Given your explanation I guess you didn't create a knapsack (or any other name you prefer) folder under plugins. Just create it and put the jar within that folder.

Comment: Thanks, I wish the official documentation would include this very helpful information :-)

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, there are some bits missing in the doc but that specific information was discussed on the google group and shared afterwards. I updated my answer with a couple of links.

Comment: the _plugin/?pretty is white screen of nothing.

Comment: @AlexanderMorland What do you mean exactly?

Comment: that even though I have 3 plugins installed and /_plugin/paramedic/ does show me that plugin page, I can not get /_plugin/ with or without the ?pretty to tell me anything, that url gives an empty response.

Comment: @AlexanderMorland Do you mean you would expect the list of installed plugins? that's available only since 0.90.